# ggplot plotting the y-axis values in wrong order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking at two basic columns in R. Year and oil price. I just want to plot them but I so not know why it is not plotting the Y axis values correctly.

```
price = read.csv("data/bp_oilprices.csv")
colnames(price) = c("Year","Dollars_of_the_day")
qplot(as.numeric(price$Year),as.numeric(price$Dollars_of_the_day))
```

Some of the data

[image: Data]

Plot output (sorry I know the x axis is a bit messy at the moment)

[image: Plot Output]

On the Y-axis notice how 109.66 is under 11.53 also 111.67 is under 12.72. I cannot figure out why this happens. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: I looks like `Dollars_of_the_day` is a factor, not a numeric variable. If you expect it to be a number (which you seem to), then there is some non-numeric values in that column in your `.csv` file. Fix that up and reimport or translate the factor labels to numeric values.

Comment: Thanks yeah it wasn't numeric. When I tried to convert it the decimal messed me up. Thanks for your help!